# Call a function in another Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created 2 different "exe" with pyinstaller.
I need pass arguments from program1 to program2 or run functions in program2 with program1's button click event, while programs are running.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Keep both program1 and program2 in same folder,

```
#In program2.py
import program1  #or import specific function alone with "from program1 import myBtnClick"
program1.myBtnClick()
```

Or to be specific,

```
from program1 import myBtnClick
myBtnClick()
```